# Move window to next screen with focus

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell-extension, extension

I have been using unity interface for last 10 years and recently started using Gnome and completely happy with the flexibility it offers using extension. However, one major issue which i have been facing is to switch/cycle windows in multi monitor setup.

I have 3 monitors setup. Gnome 3.36 (ubuntu 20.04) has this keyboard shortcut configured for "move window one monitor to the left/right" which works fine. But this behaviour has 2 problems

- Once the window is put to next monitor it doesn't focus that window
- The windows are not cycled i.e if you are on 3rd monitor and press to shift window right , it should appear to first screen but nothing happens. so you have to switch between left/right and also first hover mouse on the screen to be moved. This makes the moving process very slow in case you have to move window 2 monitors away.

In unity i used to use putwindows plugin in compiz config and that used to do this job awesomely. There's a Gnome extension also for [putWindows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/) but that also has the same two above problems. Any other solution or combination of extension can be used to work around this ?